# RNA second structure regexp pattern for HTML5

Tags: regex, html, bioinformatics

I need a RegExp to identify RNA Second structure in an HTML5 web page.

An RNA Second Structure is simply a string that contains ONLY dot points and balancing parentheses and it's used to identify the RNA shape and if we know the target RNA shape we could guess the sequence of bases that could make an RNA with that target shape.
Please note it should contains at least One dot `.`.

For example

```
.....((((...).))..)....
(((....)))
....(((..)))...()...(....((..)))
```

are true RNA Second Structures but

```
.....((((....)))...
....a.((((......))))......
((((()))))
```

are not true structures

These are all my failed attempts to identifying structures:

```
<input type="text" pattern="/[.()]/g" />
<input type="text" pattern="/[.()]/g" />
<input type="text" pattern="/[\.\(\)]/g" />
<input type="text" pattern="/[().]/g" />
<input type="text" pattern="/[()\.]/g" />
<input type="text" pattern="/[\.()]/g" />
```

I'm new to RegExp and I should publish my program in the web because my teacher ordered me to do so!
And PLEASE just tell me the RegExp I should use! My program ( libRNA ) itself checks the balancing of parentheses!
[libRNA](http://mostafa.ut.ac.ir/libRNA/)

Comment: How important is the balancing part? Because it's impossible to use ECMAScript regexes for this.

Comment: Also, in your second example, the part before the `a` *would*  be a valid sequence, right?

Comment: @TimPietzcker : yes. both strings before and after 'a' are are valid sequences.  
and I told that just for knowledge. My program (libRNA) itself checks the balancing parentheses.  
[libRNA](http://mostafa.ut.ac.ir/libRNA/)

Answer (score 2):

It is **impossible** to do *generalized* bracket balancing (finitely many nesting levels of brackets) with the level of support of JavaScript `RegExp`. (In Perl, PCRE, .NET regular expression, it is possible to do generalized bracket balancing).

You can write a simple JavaScript function to check, though:

```
function isValidSequence(str) {
    if (!/\./.test(str)) {
        // Dot . not found
        return false;
    }

    var openBrackets = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === "(") {
            openBrackets++;
        } else if (str[i] === ")") {
            if (openBrackets > 0) {
                openBrackets--;
            } else {
                // Reject the case ..)(..
                return false;
            }
        } else if (str[i] !== ".") {
            // Garbage character, since it is not . or ( or )
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Check all brackets are properly closed
    return openBrackets === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/[().]+/g
```

would match everything that looks like an RNA Second Structure (i. e. a continuous sequence of dots and parentheses). You should first use this regex to find possible matches.

Then, you can check whether at least one dot is contained within each of those matches using

```
if (submatch.indexof(".") != -1)
```

But you can't check whether the parentheses are correctly balanced - for that you need a parser like nhahtdh suggested.

Comment: not every time!
if you enter just opening and closing parentheses, yes it's invalid but if your sequence have something similar to () it could be a valid one like this:
(((..((..)))).)...()...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that what you actually need to match is:

```
a = . | .(a) | (a). | .a | a.
```

The main problem why solving this with regular expressions will be hard if not impossible is that for every opening paranthesis there has to be a closing one.

It should be possible to do this with JavaScript. You need to do something like this:

Set paranthesis counter to `0`. Iterate over the entire structure. When an opening paranthesis is found, increase counter. If you find a closing parenthesis, decrease the counter.

If at the end of the parsing the counter is back to zero, the structure is ok. Only thing missing now is the required dot. For that I would introduce another variable `justOpened` or something similar. When you find an opening paranthesis you set it to `true`. When you find a dot you set it to `false`. If you find a closing parenthesis and your variable is `true` you can abort, because your structure is broken.

Comment: I assumed this is homework, which is why I didn't provide any code but merely guidance.

Comment: not a home work, but it's a form to give sequence from user and returns the RNA structure!  
here is the webpage that you could see the form. input some structure and see what you give!  
[libRNA](http://mostafa.ut.ac.ir/libRNA)  
I just wrote the libRNA program itself and I have not enough knowledge about web programming!